# Unity 3D/C#: Rotate Camera around Object Given the Object's Height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

[image]

Given the following diagram, I am trying to accomplish the following.  Does anyone know how to do this?

**Notes**:

1. The black line represents a sample trajectory of how the ball will (randomly) fly.
2. The camera should always remain the same distance away from the ball, indicated by the orange lines.
3. The Camera's height should be relative to the ball's height, but where the angle of the camera changes.  (e.g. if the ball is high, the camera is above it, and if the ball is lower, the camera should have a lower angle.)
4. Extra Credit: Lowest possible angle should be 5 degrees, and highest possible angle should be 80 degrees.